# Is that possible to create method inside method?

Tags: java, methods

I want to create another method and i can't success with that.
Is that even possible?

```
    public void a() {
            System.out.println(...);
            public void b(){//This is the method that i want to create.
                System.out.println(...);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you *trying* to declare one method inside another? (I'd also strongly recommend using more descriptive names...)

Comment: A: You can't have a method in a method. B: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a method inside a method.

You can define an anonymous inner class inside a method, that then has a method, which you also do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a closing `}` for `check2`.  And you cannot create nested methods:

```
 public void check2() {
    label_11.setText(textField.getText());
    textField.setText("");
    System.out.println("Done 2");
 } //<--- You need to close this method
    public void check22(){//this is the method that i want to create.
        if (i2 == 590) {
        i2 = 600;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer = new Timer(false);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            // You cannot create nested methods, so this isn't valid either:
            @Override
            public void run() {
                i2--;
                label_1.setText(Integer.toString(i2));
                if (i2 == 590) {
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
      }else{

      }
    }

}
```

Comment: he wants a nested method

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the safe side, you're can't declare a method within a method. You're can declare an `anonymous class` within a method, and that `anonymous class` can be *passed* your implementation of the methods that it needs to be instantiated.

Your original method is missing a `}`. You can not declare methods inside of methods in this way.

Another option here is to look at the command pattern. For example:

```
public interface Command { 
    public void execute();
}
```

You can then create classes, as follows:

```
public class HelloCommand implements Command {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Now, you can access a class, and it can be *invoked* like a method.

```
Command hello = new HelloCommand();

hello.execute(); // prints "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `Closure` which is well known in all dynamic languages. In Java 8 `lambdas` can be used for such case, and in Java 7-- - an `anonymous inner class`

Answer (score 0):

Java >Version 8 does not support "directly" nested methods.

So you should create 2 seperate methods like this.

```
public class test {

    public void check2() {
        label_11.setText(textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");
        System.out.println("Done 2");

    }

    public void check22() {// this is the method that i want to create.
        if (i2 == 590) {
            i2 = 600;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer = new Timer(false);
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    i2--;
                    label_1.setText(Integer.toString(i2));
                    if (i2 == 590) {
                        this.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        } else {

        }
    }

}
```

If it really is necesarry, for you to have local methods, switch to Java 8 and use Lambdas or define an anonymous inner class inside of your method like this:

```
public class test {

    public void check2() {
        label_11.setText(textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");
        System.out.println("Done 2");

        class localclass {

            public void check22() {// this is the method that i want to create.
                if (i2 == 590) {
                    i2 = 600;
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer = new Timer(false);
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            i2--;
                            label_1.setText(Integer.toString(i2));
                            if (i2 == 590) {
                                this.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000);
                } else {

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```